# Using std::format with types that have operator<<

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

With the [fmt](https://fmt.dev) library, you can easily format types that have `operator<<` defined. As [explained here](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ostream-api), you extend `ostream_formatter` with one line of code:

```
template <> struct fmt::formatter<Foo> : ostream_formatter {};
```

Now you can do this:

```
fmt::format("Foo is {}", Foo());
```

Is a similar thing possible with [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format)? I have types for which `operator<<` is already defined, so I'd like to start using them with `std::format()`.

If I try to write my own formatter, I don't see how I can get an `ostream` from the arguments in the `format()` member function.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ostream_formatter : std::formatter<T> {
    constexpr auto parse(std::format_parse_context& ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }   
    auto format(const T& obj, auto& ctx) const {
        ostream out = ???;
        out << obj;
        ...
    }
};
```

Is it better to write the formatters directly and not depend on `operator<<`?

Comment: I think you'd have to make your own `std::stream_buf` which writes to the iterator from the context

Comment: You can check [`fmtlib` implementation](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/ostream.h#L123-L153), although it uses some stuff that are not available in the standard (e.g. `basic_memory_buffer`). If you're not worried about performance, I guess you could simple use a string stream and then return `std::format("{}", ss.str())`.

Comment: There is no point in using `std::format("{}", ss.str())` when you can just use `ss.str()` as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a string stream to output the value to and then retrieve its content as the result, e.g.

```
#include <format>
#include <string_view>
#include <sstream>

template <typename Char>
struct basic_ostream_formatter : std::formatter<std::basic_string_view<Char>, Char> {
  template <typename T, typename OutputIt>
  auto format(const T& value, std::basic_format_context<OutputIt, Char>& ctx) const
      -> OutputIt {
    std::basic_stringstream<Char> ss;
    ss << value;
    return std::formatter<std::basic_string_view<Char>, Char>::format(
        ss.view(), ctx);
  }
};

using ostream_formatter = basic_ostream_formatter<char>;
```

Then

```
template <> struct std::formatter<ClassWithOstream> : ostream_formatter {};
```

With a few precautions

1. This works as-is with MSVC >= 16.11. For MSVC prior to 16.11 that supports `std::format`, you need to remove the `const`-qualifier on the `format` member function.
2. This works with libc++ (version 15 or later), but you need to replace `ss.view()` with `ss.str()`.
3. This may not work with libstdc++ since `<format>` is not supported (yet).

---

Some of this is adapted from [{fmt} implementation](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/ostream.h#L123-L153) except {fmt} uses its own [`basic_memory_buffer`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/98699719f85445e0ab4a962c0b1a2a0218289814/include/fmt/format.h#L889) with a `std::basic_ostream` instead of `std::basic_stringstream`.

Comment: I'm using clang and libc++ (latest HEAD) and it still doesn't have `ss.view()` :(.  But the rest works. It does have `formatter`. I'll use `ss.str()`. Since I'm not obsessed with performance here - it's more about getting things working quickly - this is fine with me for now.